# Morning riddle from dream

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> One early morning
>
> I was half sleeping
>
> This riddle wording
>
> I found in head sitting :

(here the riddle begins)

> Nobody have it,
>
> That I can say,
>
> But if you give it,
>
> You get the same

---

(Well, this is translation, so all typos on my head, those are not part of riddle. The orginal (in Czech) came to me in dream in this form):

> Jednou po ránku
>
> napůl v polospánku
>
> jsem vymyslel hádanku:

.

> Nikdo to nemá,
>
> to není lež,
>
> však když to dáš,
>
> tak to dostaneš.

---

**Solved** already (SteveV nailed it ) :)

> That surely is 
>  Kiss on the lips :)

Or in Czech

> Tohle je dojista 
>  polibek na ústa :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New guess
Is it

> a kiss on the lips

Because

> no one has "a kiss", but if you give it, you get one back too

Comment: Nice try, but it is not, what I had in mind. Sometimes you give nothing, but still get something back.

Comment: @gilhad tried again

Comment: Yes, it is it :)

Comment: Only little more specific, as the place also have an effect if you get it back or not :)

Comment: @gilhad made it more specific

Comment: Yes, exactly that :) I already wrote ny solution under the riddle. (Could not came with good rhyme for your term, but in Czech it alredy was so :))

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a

> Punch?

Because

> Nobody can have a punch, but if you give a punch you’d better expect one in return.

Comment: The direction of your thinking is good, but  the part "get the same" is `automatic result`, not just `expectable` here in this riddle :)